# Image on top of background-image

Tags: html, css

Obviously I'm not doing this right. I'm trying to get my logo ontop of my header which is .head. How would I go about doing this? When I do it with the way provided below, my image pops above my header and not on it.

**Markup**

```
<img src="\logo.png" width="96" height="82">
<div class="head"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.head {background-image:url('header_bg.png'); top repeat-x; height: 110px;} 

body {padding:0; margin:0;}
```

Comment: There's no good way to change element order using CSS - all the workarounds come with downsides. Just put it inside the element if at all possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the image tag inside the div?

```
<div class="head">
    <img src="\logo.png" width="96" height="82">
</div>
```

Example of centering the `img` inside the div, horizontally only:

```
<div class="head">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100">
</div>

.head {
    width: 300px; height: 300px;
    background: transparent url(http://placekitten.com/300/300) no-repeat;    
}

.head img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
```

Comment: Oh... I'm new to HTML & CSS still and I didn't think you was able to put a img inside a div. So sorry. I feel so stupid now...

Comment: No worries, a "div" is a general element, you can put pretty much anything inside it. Think of it like a "frame".

Comment: I tried to center it, with align="middle" after the width and height and it doesn't affect it. Why is this?

Comment: It's sort of out of scope of the question, please have a look at w3schools or any other beginner HTML/CSS pages. I've updated the example to center horizontally for you. If you have any further questions, please post them as new questions.

Comment: Please don't go to w3schools, (here's why: http://w3fools.com/) but feel free to look in other documentation pages like MDN's. Basically align works mainly for tables, and is actually deprecated in the latest HTML standards. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put `<img>` tag inside `<div>` tag as follow:

```
<div class="head"><img src="\logo.png" width="96" height="82"></div>
```